# response text java servlet in ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, httpresponse

I want to display error message but I not clear get the error message. I just want display just the message, but in my case I show the message and the tag html, I already change the content type to text/plain. my code:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.sendError(response.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "user atau pass salah men!");
```

in error message in ajax, I alert(error.responseText); show:

user atau pass salah men!

how to get the message without the html tag? thanks

Comment: the error message show with html tag, body tag, and head tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `response.sendError` the container is generating an html page with your message. What you need to do instead is get an OutputStream from the response with `response.getOutputStream()` and write your message to it.

You can write your message to the stream with:

```
response.getOutputStream().write("user atau pass salah men!".getBytes());
```